# What is the best plugin or way to create Email Verification right now?

Tags: email-verification

I want to create an email verification for new users on my site.  This is to prevent bot spam sign ups. The user has to click on a link from their email in order to verify their account.

What's the best way to go about achieving this? I have tried purchasing a script for it, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There are many plugin provided by wordpress.org for email verification but all the plugins are not compatible with ur wp-version but this plugin is very good and compatible with wordpress latest version also .It's provided by "miniorange"and plugin name is **"Email Verification / SMS verification / Mobile Verification".**
I have also provided the link below-

https://wordpress.org/plugins/miniorange-otp-verification

Comment: I had tried this plugin and they don't provide support for the particular registration form that I need as it was custom made by a theme.